# Understanding JavaScript 'this'

Tags: javascript

When I run the following code, `this` returns `[object Object]` and then returns `[object Window]`. I understand that `this` refers to the owner of the function. I understand that `window` is the owner of the function in the latter case. But who is the owner of the function in the former case? In that case, who is `[object Object]`?

```
function Customer(name) {
    this.name = name;
    alert(this);
}

var x = new Customer('John');
Customer('Smith');
```

Comment: "*'this' refers to the owner of the function*". No, it doesn't. *this* is set by how a function is called, the use of *bind*, or lexically for *arrow* functions.

Answer (score 1):

`this`, in the former case, is the newly created object instance that will later be assigned to `x`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `new Constructor(arguments…)`, an instance of `Constructor` is created (a new object inheriting `Constructor.prototype`), and then `Constructor` is called with `this` set to that new instance. That’s just what [the `new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) does, like this:

```
var x = Object.create(Customer.prototype);
Customer.call(x, 'Smith');
```

Note that the global object (`window`) is the default when you directly call a function that isn’t a property of something; it doesn’t have to do with it being global, for example.

Answer (score 1):

"This" is how a function refers to itself.  So the name variable is passed into the function but then a *different* variable, this.name, is set within the function "Customer."  The name that belongs to customer is referred to as this.name.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a reference to an object

When you call a function with the new keyword or add a function to an object it assigns the reference to that object to `this`. In the case of the `new` keyword the function also returns the reference to the object, which is the same as `this`

```
function Test(name){
    this.myName = name;
}

var t = new Test("Obj1");
console.log(t.myName );  // Obj1
Test("Obj2");  // no reference is created and the this keyword stays as is.
console.log(this.myName ); // Obj2
// which is the same as 
console.log(window.myName ); // Obj2
```